# How to increase search size > 10,000 in elasticsearch in R?

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I have been trying to query elasticsearch from R using `elastic` package.

I was able to query and get data with

```
`Search(index = "tmp_test_data", 
           q = "_type: random AND log.type: regular", size = 10000)`
```

However, when I try to increase the `size` by adding body

```
`body1 <- '{"settings" : {"index" : {"max_result_window" : "170000"}}}'`
```

to the search query

```
`Search(index = "tmp_test_data", 
           q = "_type: random AND log.type: regular", body = body1)`
```

it returns, `Error: 400 - Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [settings].`

**Edit:**
I have tried looping through using the `from` argument in `search` function with each search `size = 1000` which is returning upto 10,000 records and throws `Error: 500 - all shards failed` after that.

I have  also tried with `elastic::scroll`, `tm_scroll = "5m"` in the `search` function by following some of the examples given in the R documentation/help but it is returning the same error `Error: 500 - all shards failed`.

What is the appropriate way to increase the size of query in R elasticsearch?

Comment: default max is 10K for Elasticsearch. as said below you can change it in your settings. often recommended for when you want lots of data is using scroll functionality, see `elastic::scroll`

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into my question. I have edited my question with more trials. I didn't get more than 10K results.

Comment: you can't change the 10K default limit in a query, you have to do that in the settings for the Elasticsearch installation. I've not actually done it myself, but the docs should help. Do look into verbose stack traces from Elasticsearch by doing `connect(errors = "complete")` - which should give insight into what's going wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to update a [dynamic index setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html).  You cannot include it as part of a search.

To update it, you need to update it using the [Update Settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html).  I'm not sure how to do it with R but here is a http request example.

```
PUT http://myserver:9200/tmp_test_data/_settings

{  
    "index" : {
        "max_result_window": 170000
    }
}
```